# Define variable within function parameter value

Tags: php, twitter

I wanted to know whether i can pass a globally defined variable within a function parameter value. e.g.

```
$tweetsdisplayed = 40;
function display_latest_tweets(
  $twitter_user_id,
  $cache_file          = './tweets.txt',
  $tweets_to_display   = $tweetsdisplayed)
{
```

Currently, the option above is not working, even when i dont pass it as a variable `tweetsdisplayed`. Whats the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function
>   call.

but you can use [$_GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).
e.g.:

```
$tweetsdisplayed = 40;

function display_latest_tweets(
  $twitter_user_id,
  $cache_file          = './tweets.txt',
  $tweets_to_display   = null)
{
    $tweets_to_display = isset($tweets_to_display) ? $tweets_to_display : $_GLOBALS['tweetsdisplayed'];
}
```